# why i can not access the element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following markup :

```
<div class="tutor-photo-slider">
     <ul>
         <li><a class="left-arrow" href="javascript:;"></a></li>
         <li>
         <ul id="carousel">
             <li>
                 <a href="/assets/images/tutor-sample.png" class="slider-image">
                 <img src="/assets/images/tutor-sample-thumb.png" /></a>
             </li>
         </ul>
         </li>
   <li>
      <a class="right-arrow" href="javascript:;"></a>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

when I do

```
$('.left-arrow').click(function() {
    var elem = $(this).parents('ul').children('li').children('ul'),
        children = elem.children('li');
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if ($(children[i]).css('display') != 'none') {
            break;
        }
    }
    $(children[i - 1]).show();
});
```

it doesn't access it.I tried debugging it in firebug but could not figure out the error.
I am including jquery 1.6.4. And I do not have errors.

edit: I am trying to make a carousel photo gallery http://jsfiddle.net/5xHFT/1/

Comment: *it doesn't access it*: What does that mean?

Comment: Are you running the code inside the `ready` event handler, or inside a script tag below the element that you try to access?  Otherwise the  element simply doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I am running the code inside jQuery(function($){ //code });

Comment: You should create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo for your problem and clearly explain what your code is supposed to do and what it actually does. You basically just say "it does not work" which is not a very helpful error description (and gave you many unhelpful answers).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5xHFT/ I am trying to make a carousel gallery.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet is missing an

```
);
```

As in, instead of

```
$('.left-arrow').click(function() {}
```

do ...

```
$('.left-arrow').click(function() {} );
```

That can cause the error.

Answer (score 1):

click function missing the closing brackets. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NkCGQ/5/) is working code.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comment by Guffa, you probably are not doing this inside `ready`. Here is a fiddle to show you: http://jsfiddle.net/AVGTL/

after looking at the other fiddle, it is really just the missing `)`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 jQuery('.left-arrow').click(function() {} );
```

some times using some plug-ins make some conflicts so just try  to use jQuery instead of "$"

Comment: I am using jQuery(function($){ //code }); so it is ok to use the $ inside

Answer (score 0):

Seems okay with snippet which you have provided: http://jsfiddle.net/8zgqF/1/. Specify your question.